Firebase Messaging data not exported to linked BigQuery
On a Firebase project messaging data has been set up to export to BigQuery (integration set up in Firebase console, it says it is exporting 13/13 apps)
However even after waiting several days no data is showing up in BigQuery. The table in the BigQuery side exists.
In BigQuery, the batch jobs that were automatically scheduled on Firebase > BigQuery linkage and that should transfer the data repeatedly show these messages which I think might point to the problem:
"Transfer deferred due to source data not being available"
Now I've successfully sent a few notifications from Firebase console to app, and have also opened these apps. I have verified these notifications in Reports in Firebase, so data definitely does exist in Firebase side. This data exists for a date two days from now.
What could be wrong?

It took somewhere between 2-3 days (as in 24 hour cycles) but the data finally appeared in BigQuery. Case closed, maybe not a real problem (I might delete this question) but I figured that it could help some people wondering why data doesn't appear even waiting for 24+ hours.
